# Generating a report by date range in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, report, date-range

How would you go about producing reports by user selected date ranges in a rails app?  What are the best date range pickers?

edit in response to patrick : I am looking for a bit of both widget and active record advice but what I am really curious about is how to restfully display a date ranged list based on user selected dates.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Are we asking an interface question here (i.e. you want a widget) or an ActiveRecord question?

## Date Picking Widgets

1)  **Default Rails Solution**: See `date_select` documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html).

2)  **Use a plugin** : Why write code?  I personally like the [CalendarDateSelect](http://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/) plugin, using a pair of the suckers when I need a range.

3)  **Adapt a Javascript widget to Rails**: It is almost trivial to integrate something like the Yahoo UI library (YUI) [Calendar](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/calendar/), which is all Javascript, to Rails.  From the perspective of Rails its just another way to populate the `params[:start_date]` and `params[:end_date]`.  YUI Calendar has native support for ranges.

## Getting the data from the Widgets

1)  **Default Rails Solution**  See `date_select` documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html).

```
#an application helper method you'll find helpful
#credit to http://blog.zerosum.org/2007/5/9/deconstructing-date_select

# Reconstruct a date object from date_select helper form params
def build_date_from_params(field_name, params)
  Date.new(params["#{field_name.to_s}(1i)"].to_i, 
       params["#{field_name.to_s}(2i)"].to_i, 
       params["#{field_name.to_s}(3i)"].to_i)
end

#goes into view
<%= date_select "report", "start_date", ... %>
<%= date_select "report", "end_date", ... %>    

#goes into controller -- add your own error handling/defaults, please!
report_start_date = build_date_from_params("start_date", params[:report])
report_end_date = build_date_from_params("end_date", params[:report])
```

2)  **CalendarDateSelect**: Rather similar to the above, just with sexier visible UI.

3)  **Adapt a Javascript widget**: Typically this means that some form element will have the date input as a string.  Great news for you, since Date.parse is some serious magic.  The params[:some_form_element_name] will be initialized by Rails for you.

```
#goes in controller.  Please handle errors yourself -- Javascript != trusted input.
report_start_date = Date.parse(params[:report_start_date])
```

## Writing the call to ActiveRecord

Easy as pie.

```
  #initialize start_date and end_date up here, by pulling from params probably
  @models = SomeModel.find(:all, :conditions => ['date >= ? and date <= ?',
    start_date, end_date])
  #do something with models
```

Comment: A bit of both widget and active record but what I am really curious about is how to restfully display a date ranged list based on user selected dates.  Specifically, how best to get the input from the user into the active record find.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of expanding my answer to be more helpful to you.

Comment: shouldn't build_date_from_params go into the application controller rather than the application helper?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an unRESTful practice to have URL parameters control the range of selected records. In your index action, you can do what Patrick suggested and have this:

```
  #initialize start_date and end_date up here, by pulling from params probably
  @models = SomeModel.find(:all, :conditions => ['date >= ? and date <= ?', params[:start_date], params[:end_date]])
```

Then in your index view, create a form that tacks on ?start_date=2008-01-01&end_date=2008-12-31 to the URL. Remember that it's user-supplied input, so be careful with it. If you put it back on the screen in your index action, be sure to do it like this:

```
Showing records starting on 
<%= h start_date %> 
and ending on 
<%= h end_date %>
```