# How do I create a form that submits two dates and outputs the report?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, date, controller

I currently have a controller which produces a report.  This is the controller:

```
def last5days

    #@monday = (Time.now).at_beginning_of_week

    @monday = (Time.now).months_ago(1)
    #@friday = 5.days.since(@monday)-1.second
    @friday = (Time.now)
    @sent_emails = ContactEmail.all(:conditions => ['date_sent >= ? and date_sent <= ?', @monday, @friday])

    @made_calls = ContactCall.all(:conditions => ['date_sent >= ? and date_sent <= ?', @monday, @friday])

    @letters_sent = ContactLetter.all(:conditions => ['date_sent >= ? and date_sent <= ?', @monday, @friday])

    @contacts_added = Contact.all(:conditions => ['date_entered >= ? and date_entered <= ?', @monday, @friday])

    #@table = ContactEmail.report_table(:all,
     #                                   :conditions => ['date_sent >= ? and date_sent <= ?', @monday, @friday])

    #@grouping = Grouping(@table, :by => "email_id")                                    

  end
```

Instead of hardcoding `monday` and `friday`, I want to have an interface where someone can select the start and end dates, hit submit, and the output gets returned.

I'm having troubling finding an example or knowing exactly what to do.

I started with a new view:

```
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>


<div id = 'display'>

</div>
```

I want the output from the controller to be displayed in "display" via Ajax.

I tried to create the form as follows:

```
<% remote_form_for  do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :start_date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select_tag :start_date %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :end_date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select_tag :end_date %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>


 <% end %>
```

And then my plan was to change the controller to accept `params[:start_date]` and `params[:end_date]`

But I don't think I quite know how the pieces fit together to make this work.  Guidance?  Help?

**Here is what I am trying now:**

VIEW:  find_start_end.html.erg

```
<% form_tag('return_search') do %>
  <p>
    <label>Start Date</label> <%= date_select('start_date', 'params') %>|
     <label>End Date</label> <%= date_select :end_date, params[:end_date] %>
  </p>
  <p><%= submit_tag "Get Stats" %></p>
<% end %>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
def return_search

    @sent_emails = ContactEmail.all(:conditions => ['date_sent >= ? and date_sent <= ?', params[:start_date], params[:end_date]])

    @made_calls = ContactCall.all(:conditions => ['date_sent >= ? and date_sent <= ?', params[:start_date], params[:end_date]])

    @letters_sent = ContactLetter.all(:conditions => ['date_sent >= ? and date_sent <= ?', params[:start_date], params[:end_date]])

    @contacts_added = Contact.all(:conditions => ['date_entered >= ? and date_entered <= ?', params[:start_date], params[:end_date]])

    respond_to do |format|

      format.html #view needs to be the same name as the method

    end 

    def find_start_end

    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make sure you get a basic HTML version up first
2) Then transfer this to Ajax.

This flow gets everyone on board and keeps logic organized.

All of your logic is correct so I will just give you the code for the HTML version and once you get that up you can get the remote version going.

controller:

```
 def index
       @start_date = Date.strptime(params[:start_date],"%d/%m/%Y")
       @end_date = Date.strptime(params[:end_date],"%d/%m/%Y")
       @stuffs = Stuff.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at > ? and updated_at < ?",@start_date, @end_date])
      responds_to do |format|
          format.html #view needs to be the same name as the method
      end 
 end
```

view

```
<% form_tag(stuffs_path, :method => :get) do %>
  <p>
    <label>Start Date</label> <%= datetime_select :start_date, params[:start_date] %> |
     <label>End Date</label> <%= datetime_select :end_date, params[:end_date] %>
  </p>
  <p><%= submit_tag "Get Stats", :disable_with => "Getting stats..." %></p>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

you need a line at the top like this:

```
map.resources :stuffs
```

Basically what this does is create specific routes.
Now you can call `stuffs_path` and it will go to the index action.

If you are not using REST the search_stuff_path could be :controller => :your_controller => :action => your_action. IF you are using REST you need to add this as a member to your routes.rb in config. If you need more info let me know.

BTW - I used stuffs to be a generic term for your resource. I think what you want would be report so the controller, routes, and views would be reports_path and map.resources :reports respectively.

So now that you got the HTML version going it's easy to get remote going.

controller

```
def index
    responds_to do |format|
        format.js render :partial => "remote_report"
        # you can use RJS or a partial. 
        # If it's one place you want to update just use a partial.
        # Create a file _remote_report.html.erb as a partial.
        # Put this in the views folder of course
    end 
end
```

In your view:

```
 <div id="div_id_to_update">
 <% remote_form_tag(stuffs_path, :method => :get, :update => "div_id_to_update") do %>
   <p>
     your form methods here
   </p>
   <p>your submit tag here</p>
 <% end %>
 </div>
```

Those are the parts you need to change to make it remote based.

Comment: thanks...I *should* be using rest :) but does that mean I create a custom route called search_stuff_path ?

Comment: Yeah, if your using rails is more of a pain not to use rest. I didn't use it for a long time because it's a strange concept but once you use it it sticks with rails DRY and Convention over configuration which helps productivity

Comment: I will edit the code and be more specific about what needs to be done with rest

Comment: Let me know if you have more questions :)

Comment: is there a way that I can have the inputs formatted as dates rather than using text_fields?

Comment: cool, thanks -- this is what did in the routes:    map.connect 'reports/find_start_end',
            :controller => 'reports',
            :action => 'find_start_end'  is that right?

Comment: Yeah, you need to use datetime_select. I will check it out and post what i get.

Comment: I don't know exactly how this will work in the controller. I assume it should be OK. If you don't want the datetime_select as a helper then it will be more work but its still possible to create your own datetime_select options.

Comment: cool, I used date_select and it looks like it will post the value....so I guess I need to figure out what the controller is to display the actual output

Comment: oh wait, i see -- actually the find stuffs is what is posted to...so it posts to itself?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I forgot to put something important in the search form so check that out.

Comment: I added the method to the search form this is for http requests and informs the server what you want. Get means find

Comment: Hi, why do you wrap the params with #{ }? does that create the string value for the date?

Comment: actually you don't need that. You can just do params[:start_date]

Comment: okay -- hmmm I am getting a funky sql I have a slight modification from what you have but not significant.  Let me post it

Comment: it seems like it posts the date as month, day, and year as a hash in params...so I get this:  




- (2i)   
- "6"
' and date_sent <= '---
- (3i)
- "13"
','---
- (1i)
- "2010"
','---
- (2i)
- "8"
') ):

Comment: ah, date_select passes as multiparameter...but how do you convert multiparameter into something that can be passed into a sql statement for :conditions?

Comment: too much work to convert and who needs seconds anyways. Try the code I added and then you will need to create custom drop downs for the dates

Comment: yeah I am using date_select instead of datetime...this creates drop-down for the dates which works.  The multi-parameter thingy is what's funky...if I could just have a .to_s type method that would fix it...but not sure...

Comment: probably gave you lots of error with the last code. The latest might work.

Comment: phew!  okay, based on what you did, I got something working...not using ajax, but it's working.  I used another stackoverflow to help with the multiparameter conversion:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138496/generating-a-report-by-date-range-in-rails

Comment: so...let me post onto a gist the latest of stuff I got...I *think* I am ready to make it work with ajax remote_forms.!

Comment: cool, it works as desired as separate html forms (I use post insetad of get):

http://gist.github.com/524049

Comment: great! Don't use post though. Post is for creating records. 'get' is for finding records. huge difference

Comment: ah, okay, let me add that...tomorrow will tackle the remote_for unless you have a suggestion :)